# Qt DragLeaveEvent not being called when leaving with a drag operation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a row of buttons, each of which can accept drops. However, when I leave a button with my cursor with another button being dragged, the 'dragLeaveEvent' is not being called.

```
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
            mime = QtCore.QMimeData()
            mime.setText("f")
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            drag.exec_()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print "enter"

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        print "leave"


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        for i in range(10):
            btn = Button()
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(btn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: do you use `Python 2`? `Python 3` would need `print("enter")` with `()` ?

Comment: Python 2. Anyways, I would've gotten an error if the code reached that part with Py3....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation about [`dragEnterEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#dragEnterEvent) reports (it's from Qt5, but the same was valid for Qt4 also):

> If the event is ignored, the widget won't receive any drag move events.

Note: **any drag move events**.
This also means *drop* events.

By default, all drag events are ignored for most widgets *if the drag enter event is not accepted*, so if you want to *receive* all events (including the *leave* event) that first event **must** be accepted.

```
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    # ...
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        print "enter"
```